recv doesn't work in a thread - Windows c++
I'm currently developing a TCP server and I use multi threading, so for this I init a server using a Server.start() which give me a fd like and then I init an infinite loop to accept and start new thread like this:
int main()
{
    spdlog::set_pattern("[%H:%M:%S %z] [%^---%L---%$] [thread %t] %v");

    Server server(9001);
    int sockfd = server.start();

    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        spdlog::error("Cannot init server");
        return 1;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        int fd = server.loop();
        std::thread t(newclient, fd);
    }
}

void newclient(int fd)
{
    Handler handler;
    handler.loop(fd);
    closesocket(fd);
};

handler.loop:
void Handler::loop(int fd){
    std::string buffer;

    Communication communication(fd);

    while(true){
        buffer.erase();
        buffer = communication.recv_str();
        if (buffer == "") {
            continue;
        }
    }
    ...
}

and communication.recv_str():
std::string Communication::recv_str(){
    std::vector<char> buffer(CHUNK_SIZE);
    std::string rcv;
    long bytes_received = 0; 

    do {
        bytes_received = recv(fd, &buffer[0], CHUNK_SIZE, 0);

        if ( bytes_received < 0 ) {
            std::cout << "recv failed, err: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        } else if ( bytes_received == 0 ) {
            return "";
        } else {
            rcv.append(buffer.cbegin(), buffer.cend());
        }
    } while( bytes_received == CHUNK_SIZE );

    return rcv;
}

so if I compile and run this when I try to connect to the server I got this message:

But for a reason which I cannot explain it's crashing at the recv, I've tried to debug it but I cannot explain this thing. No message errors or others indications, I do not understand.
PS: sending works perfectly.

There's just too little context to be able to help you. Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

" it's crashing at the recv" - what do you mean with "crashing"? Returns an error (which?), applications exits (i.e. memory fault), ... So far there is nothing obvious which could cause a crash. There is a problem though that you assume that if bytes_received is not CHUNK_SIZE then no more data will be there. recv will only read up to the given size, but is not guaranteed to read everything even if more data are sent by the peer.

Your std::thread object goes out of scope before the thread is finished. You need to put the std::thread object somewhere more permanent.

If a std::thread object is destructed and the associated thread is still running, std::terminate is called.
This is specified in the documentation:

If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called.

In this part of your code:
while (true)
{
    int fd = server.loop();
    std::thread t(newclient, fd);
}

t's scope is ending at the end of the current iteration and the std::thread object is destroyed while it is most likely still running. Therefore std::terminate is called and the program exits.
To solve the problem, you should keep all your std::thread objects as long as their associated thread is running. You could, for example, store them in a container in your Server class.
